# Need help code isn't working

Tags: c#

I am sorry to ask. But I'm new to C#.

And I have something wrong in my code (Visual Studio told me it). But I can't find what is wrong.

Can you help me?

I just trying some simple interactive game.

```
namespace FSociety
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "root"
                && textBox2.Text == "toor") ;           
            {
                progressBar1.Increment(100);

            **}**
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After bolded **}** Visual Studio is telling me to expect `}` but its already there and when I add one more I have like 5 more errors.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you have a rogue `;` after `&& textBox2.Text == "toor")`

Comment: If that's all of your code, you definitely need the bracket. So what error(s) do you get when you put it in?Taking out the semi-colon should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ; after your if statement

Comment: Yep. It worked. Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "root" && textBox2.Text == "toor") // there was a ; at the end of the if
        {
            progressBar1.Increment(100);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
        }
    }
```

Tip: If visual studio can not format code you should check all your closing tags. visual studio recognize the code structure and will make the code look better.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace FSociety {

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {

            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "root"
            && textBox2.Text == "toor")           
            {
            progressBar1.Increment(100);

            }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");

        }

    }
}

}
```

This is the working code.
in C# you don't have to put any **;** after an if(condition).

The correct syntax is:

```
if(condition)
{
    //true condition
}
else
{ 
    //false condition
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I apreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know for the future, if you ever get an error that says "Unexpected [character]" What it actually means is "Hey, I expected there to be something before that character". For instance, if I have code like this

```
function foo(){
    print 'bar'
}
```

I'm going to get an error that says " Unexepected ' } ' ". This is because the computer is expecting a semicolon right after "print 'bar'" So this would fix the error

```
function foo(){
    print 'bar';
}
```

So when you get "Unexpected X" start looking right before X for something you left out (or accidentally added in extra)

Comment: Oh okay thank you very much. :-)